# Create an application to configure Timer with C#

Tags: c#

I've created an application with C# which returns a ListView value to .txt file every 30minutes.

And I want to create a button on this application to let the users change the Timers' value without modifying the code, i.e a button to configure timer like the property Timer on Visual studio.

**Update**

```
private async void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //create file 
   using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\pc\List.txt"))
   {
      foreach (ListViewItem item in lvDetails.Items)
      {
          await tw.WriteLineAsync(item.SubItems[0].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[1].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[2].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[3].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[4].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[5].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[6].Text);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what did you tried? where's your code?

Comment: Drumroll*** and your code looks like?

Comment: To begin somewhere: WinForms, WPF, UWP, WebForms? Add a tag.

Comment: private async void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create file
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\pc\List.txt"))
           {
                
                foreach (ListViewItem item in lvDetails.Items)
                {
                    await tw.WriteLineAsync(item.SubItems[0].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[1].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[2].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[3].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[4].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[5].Text + "\t" + item.SubItems[6].Text);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: What sort of timer is it, did you drop it on your form?

Comment: I want to let everyone who use the application to change the Timer Interval.

Comment: I use this Timer to send my ListView value to .txt file

Comment: The Timer property {(Name):timer2 ; Enable :True ; Interval : 1800000 ; Modifier : Public;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a textbox on the form where you can input the interval, and a button and in the onclick event do something like this. Remember the interval is in milliseconds, so you need to cater for that if you going to ask for second or minute input in the textbox. Multiply the interval with 1000 for seconds and 60000 for minutes

```
timer2.enabled = false;
int interval;
if(int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out interval))
{
  timer2.interval =  interval;
  timer2.enabled = true;
}
else
  throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number");
```

**UPDATE:**

If the application to set the interval is the same app as where the timer actually is, there is a few ways of getting that right.

1. You can use a simple client/server socket solution to send the new interval to the timer application.
2. You can use a messaging service to send a message to the timer application.
3. You can use a db or the like (nosql, SQLite etc) to have the configuration saved for the timer app. The times app will read the interval value on every tick, and set it, or something like that, and the setter app will save the value in the db.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to make an interface where users can change the Timer Interval on the application.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Is the timer not running in the same application?

Comment: it's running on the same..

Comment: Ok, is it a windows forms app, or a console app?

Comment: Please read my complete answer from the top. If you want to add a button, add a textbox as well where the interval can be entered. Then in the click event of the button add the code I gave you.

Comment: Windows form app.. :)

Comment: Can you add a textbox on the form? and then add a button to the form? and then double click on the button, and paste the code snippet I provided in there?

Comment: there a syntaxe error on "out int interval".. :( something like "miss ',' "

Comment: Sorry, I've used c# 7.0 syntex. I've updated my answer

Comment: Is the code working now?

Comment: thank you so much.. ^_^